# mono memory leak on XMLDocument

Tags: mono, xmldocument

I found that if i make this simple project with MONO on OSX the memory of the mono process continuously grow, is there some hints to avoid this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace testXML
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            while (true) {
                XmlDocument oo = new XmlDocument (); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code in mono 2.11 on Angstrom v2012.12 (3.8.13 kernel) without the memory growth. Just wanted to share, I'm looking for a memory leak my self.